# Highcharts AreaSpline - Adding padding in between the chart and plot area

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to add padding in between my chart and plot area, as you can see in the screenshot below, the markers are overflowing across the borders of the plot area.

Is there a way for me to add padding to the bottom of the plot area, or a way to move up the chart series slightly so that it doesn't overflow?

[image: markers overflowing across the plot area]

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Asy/5/

Here is the JS code:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline',
            marginLeft: 25,
            plotBorderWidth: 2,
            plotBackgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 178],
                stops: [
                    [0.5, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(221, 221, 221)']
                ]
            },
            events: {
                load: function(){
                    this.plotBackground.attr({ rx: 15, ry: 15 });
                    this.plotBorder.attr({ rx: 15, ry: 15 });
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: { 
            enabled: false 
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            labels: {
                rotation: -90,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontFamily: 'Sterling, sans-serif',
                    color: '#999'
                },
                x: 5,
                y: 28
            }

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {

                    if(this.isFirst) {
                        return this.value;
                    }

                    return bytesToSize(this.value, 0, true);
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontFamily: 'Sterling, sans-serif',
                    color: '#999'
                },
                align: 'center',
                x: -16,
                y: 12

            },
            gridLineColor: 'transparent'
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            formatter: function() {

                var tooltip = $('<div>');
                var total = 0;

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point){
                    total += this.y;

                    tooltip.append($('<div style="color: ' + point.series.area.fill + ';">').html(point.series.name + ': ' + bytesToSize(this.y,2)));

                    if(!(i % 2)){
                        tooltip.append('<br />');
                    }

                });

                tooltip.prepend($('<div style="color: #999;">').html('Total: ' + bytesToSize(total,2) + '<br />'));

                return tooltip.get(0).outerHTML;
            }

        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                lineWidth: 1.3,
                marker: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1.3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Download',
            fillColor: 'rgba(0, 140, 194, 0.3)',
            lineColor: '#008cc2',
            data: [0,4815834355,23055591595,0,0,15404821463,0,20217522975,5521887522,0,0,1371666239,2134496,0,2948406184,12384283037,8231543133,9268703354,11368292543,1747717890,4540649201,4705338812]

        }, {
            name: 'Upload',
            fillColor: 'rgba(117, 0, 198, 0.4)',
            lineColor: '#7500c6',
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            data: [0,201112067,1160271286,0,0,748962337,0,2289905587,211355292,0,0,64669389,559747,0,368939264,954704437,385646325,453112460,251406236,131414580,312915384,153890742]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution for that, but only two workarounds:

- set min and startOnTick for xAxis, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Asy/6/

  ```
      yAxis: {
          min: -1024 * 1024 * 1024,
          startOnTick: false,
      }
  ```
- set threshold for series and startOnTick for xAxis, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Asy/7/

  ```
      yAxis: {
          startOnTick: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
          areaspline: {
              threshold: -1
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: Highcharts employee to the rescue :)

Comment: Indeed ;) Bars and area types are a little different from standard series, like line or scatter - where you can set `minPadding`.